# How can I deal with a missing or corrupt binary ("advanced") log table?

Tags: developer, logging

Sometimes I install an extension that creates a new MySQL table, but it breaks because I have binary ("advanced") logging enabled. CiviCRM tries to write to the binary log, and it fails because the table doesn't exist.

Other times, there's a corrupt binary log table, which I can only fix by dropping it.

In these situations, I know that disabling and re-enabling binary logging will fix the situation, but then I lose my existing logs!  Is there another less destructive solution?

Answer (score 4):

As of CiviCRM 4.7, you can fix this by installing any extension; see [CRM-15078](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15078).  Schema differences are fixed on extension installation.

If you are on an earlier version of CiviCRM, there's a trick you can do.  Edit the PHP for a page that doesn't normally get used - I like the API Explorer page (CRM/Admin/Page/APIExplorer.php).

Right after `public function run() {`, I put:

```
$temp = new CRM_Logging_Schema();
$temp->fixSchemaDifferences(TRUE);
echo "Binary log schema differences are now fixed.";
die;
```

Once I get back the "now fixed" message, I remove the code from the page and everything works.

Comment: I was the one who fixed that bug at the sprint, it happened to be something I had already encountered. In one of my extensions that creates a custom entity type, I put the fixSchemaDifferences stuff in the extension's hook_civicrm_enable instance, so the extension works on older versions with logging too.

Comment: Thanks, this is still a relevant solution 4 years later.