# Any OTHER way to disable DB logging (CiviCRM 4.6x)?

Tags: logging, db-logging, mariadb

Enabled logging to a DB caused "TABLE log_xxx doesn't exists" similar to [this issue](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22811/change-log-crashes-table-entity-log-civireport-doesnt-exist-how-to-fix) ; Extension installation (which should re-create LOG_ tables) has failed by the same reason. A sneaky trick from [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8706/how-can-i-deal-with-a-missing-or-corrupt-binary-advanced-log-table) hasn't worked either, due to a missing MySQL/MariaDB ARCHIVE engine, which by default is being used for LOG_ tables.

Any other options of disable logging, apart from messing with MySQL installation and temporary DB tables re-creation code insertion?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Civi 5.9 - DB Error: no such table / cannot disable logging](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/civi-5-9-db-error-no-such-table-cannot-disable-logging)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE in case anyone stumbles on this question.
There is a working answer at  [Civi 5.9 - DB Error: no such table / cannot disable logging](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/civi-5-9-db-error-no-such-table-cannot-disable-logging)